# How can I version control my little framework better?

Tags: version-control

I have a little php framework for HTML development. I basically made HTML semi-functional by writing functions that return some HTML markup. For example:

```
P('Some, text' . a('Link', '#'), 'my_class);
```

returns something like this:

```
<p class="my_class">Some, text<a href="#">Link</a></p>
```

Apart from being shorter to write, it is also a lot faster, not only because it is shorter, but because there are less weird combination of characters needed to type the function calls than there are to type the equivalent markup.

This framework is still under development, but I use it across different projects. My current layout is this:

```
~/publkic_html/
   ->core/
   ->project_1/
     ->core/
   ->project_2/
     ->core/
   ->project_3/
     ->core/
```

As you can see, the framework is called core, and I have one copy of it at the top directory, then, each project has its own copy. What I currently do, which is not any form of version control, is I copy the core on a project back to the top directory core when I make changes to the core of that project.

For example, lets imagine I'm working on project_1, and I realize there is something that I need to be added to core, so I add it. Then I copy the core on project_1 to the top core with this:

```
cp -rvu ~/public_html/project_1/core/ ~/public_html/
```

I do a recursive update. I like verbose because I can see what is being copied.

When I need to work on another project, lets say project_2, I do the opposite,  updating project_2/core/ with the contents from ~/public_html/core

As you can see this is a problem. Not only is it annoying, but it is also very prone to problems. For example, I could forget to do an update after changing a core that is local to a project. This introduces a lot of problems, like changing the same file on two different projects without updating will likely result on changes being overwritten and lost.

How can I manage this in a more efficient and safe way? Not to mention saner!

I was looking at git, but is seems that I would just end up with many different version-controlled version of core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (really - **must**) use any SCM, which allow code re-use and share (instead of cloning) (and I don't know any VCS, which does **NOT** have this feature)

1. Subversion

   - externals
2. Mercurial

   - Subrepo (guestrepo)
3. Git

   - Submodules (git-subtree)

PS: Git as first VCS is worst choice

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly look into that. Why is Git the worst choice as first VCS?

Comment: @Buzu - in order not to engage in repeat itself: [GIT - What gotchas should newcomers to version control be aware of?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114249/git-what-gotchas-should-newcomers-to-version-control-be-aware-of/114312#114312)

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely consider your advice, and start using s VCS that is not Git. Some time ago I started reading about subversion, but never really finished. I'm sure I still have that manual somewhere.